# How to get the sub type of the noun using wordnet c#

Tags: c#, wordnet

I am trying to retrieve sub type of a noun.
for ex. If I enter John then it should give sub type as noun.Person.

Currently I am using the following code

```
 WnLexicon.WordInfo wordInfo = WnLexicon.Lexicon.FindWordInfo(token, true);
 var strength = wordInfo.Strength;
 var wordType = wordInfo.partOfSpeech;
```

Using  wordInfo.partOfSpeech I am able to know the type of the word(i.e Noun,Adj).
But I want to know it's sub type as mentioned above.